# Get the value of text box in html

Tags: asp.net, razor

I am working on ASP.Net shopping card application in which I have a product detail page where an `input type="text"` is for the quantity and when the user clicks on the *Add to Cart*  button the product will be add to cart.

```
<input type="text" id="quantity" value="">

<a href="/Cart.html?Id=@Id&Quantity=?">Add to Cart </a>
```

When the user *enters the value in the textbox*, the **querystring** of cart link should be **updated**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this jquery function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#quantity").change(function (event) {

        var quantity = this.value;
        $("a[href^='/Cart.html?Id']")
        .each(function () {
            var index = this.href.lastIndexOf('=');
            var newUrl = this.href.substring(0, index);

            this.href = newUrl + "=" + quantity;
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Javascript to achieve this. Try using

```
document.getElementById['quantity'].value
```

This should return you the value of the textfield

Comment: then how can i get it in the query string?

Comment: This is not a full answer, please tell him how to automatic update the query string when the box is change.

Comment: document.location.href = "/Cart.html?Id=@Id&Quantity=" + document.getElementById['quantity'].value;

Woe betide ye who shopith here.

Comment: You are right. Apologies. In order to update your query add an id to your <a> tag (say 'quantity_a', although this is a bad name) and try something like the following:

document.getElementById('quantity_a').setAttribute('href', document.getElementById['quantity'].value);

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to do this server-side

```
<asp:TextBox ID="quantityTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="addToCartButton" runat="server" Text="Add to cart" />
```

Then on the code behind you can redirect the user

```
protected void addToCartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       string id = "your id";
       string url = String.Format("/Cart.html?Id={0}&Quantity={1}", id, quantityTextBox.Text);
       Response.Redirect(url, false);
}
```